# Unity3d rotate gameobject around arbitrary line (not through origin)

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

I would like to rotate a GameObject around an arbitrary line ( a line which doesn't have to go through the origin).

Comment: How does one "rotate around a line"?  You mean like an elliptical path around the end points or treating the line like an axis and rotating around it?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

-1 for having "Rotate" and "around" in your question, and not finding this. Internet clutter.